# Combine several "context"-Blocks in final return-clause of a view

Tags: django, django-views

Hiho, i've searched for this and found simliar topics but none of them gave me an answer that seems helpful....or I searched for the wrong terms maybe.

Right now I wonder, wether you can optionally combine the context of a "return render...." command in a Django-View. As Django propagates a "Do-Not_Repeat-Yourself" philosophy, I would like to change the following code to shorten it (The several if-clauses have to do with role-rights stuff....):

```
def show(request):

    now_day = datetime.date.today()
    current_user = request.user 

    if request.method == 'GET':

        if view_self(current_user) == True and more_rights(current_user) == False:
            if Employees.objects.filter(employee_number=current_user).exists():

                context = {'names': Employees.objects.filter(employee_number=current_user)}
            else:
                context = {'info': "Für sie existiert (noch) kein Datensatz in dieser Datenbank"}  
        else: 
            context = {'names': Employees.objects.all().order_by('last_name').values()}

        return render(request, 'show.html', context)

    else:
        if view_self(current_user) == True and more_rights(current_user) == False:

            if request.POST['id'] == 'Mitarbeiter auswählen...':
                context = {
                    'names': Employees.objects.filter(employee_number=current_user),
                    'info': "Bitte treffen Sie zuerst eine Auswahl"
                }
            else:
                employee = request.POST['id']
                context = {
                    'names': Employees.objects.filter(employee_number=current_user),
                    'entries': Employees.objects.filter(id=request.POST['id']),
                    'work_conditions': Employment.objects.filter(employee_id=request.POST['id']),
                    'functions': Functions.objects.filter(employee__functions=request.POST['id']).order_by('function'),
                    'fieldsoa': FieldsOfActivity.objects.filter(employee__fieldsofactivity=request.POST['id']).order_by('field_of_activity'),
                    'missions': Foreign_Missions.objects.filter(employee_id=request.POST['id']).order_by('-begin'),
                    'examinations': Examinations.objects.filter(employee_id=request.POST['id']).order_by('-date'),
                    'total_duration_days': Foreign_Missions.objects.total_duration_days(employee),
                    'today': now_day,
                    'special_header': "Datensätze anzeigen"
                }

        elif request.POST['id'] == 'Mitarbeiter auswählen...':
            context = {
            'names': Employees.objects.all().order_by('last_name').values(),
            'info': "Bitte treffen Sie zuerst eine Auswahl"
            }
    
        elif 'id' in request.POST:
            employee = request.POST['id']             #Employees.objects.get(pk=id)
            context = {
            'names': Employees.objects.all().order_by('last_name').values(),
            'entries': Employees.objects.filter(id=request.POST['id']),
            'work_conditions': Employment.objects.filter(employee_id=request.POST['id']),
            'functions': Functions.objects.filter(employee__functions=request.POST['id']).order_by('function'),
            'fieldsoa': FieldsOfActivity.objects.filter(employee__fieldsofactivity=request.POST['id']).order_by('field_of_activity'),
            'missions': Foreign_Missions.objects.filter(employee_id=request.POST['id']).order_by('-begin'),
            'examinations': Examinations.objects.filter(employee_id=request.POST['id']).order_by('-date'),
            'total_duration_days': Foreign_Missions.objects.total_duration_days(employee),
            'today': now_day,
            'special_header': "Datensätze anzeigen"
            }

        return render(request, 'show.html', context)
```

so my question is: can I "split" the context-lines in a practical way to put the parts that show up in every corresponding if-clause to a position near the return render command so i don't have to repeat the lines?

Update 2023-04-28:
Tried (with another module, shorter code so easier to read) the approach given with empty context and stepwise filling. won't work here:

```
def delete(request):

context = {}
context['names'] = Employees.objects.all().order_by('last_name').values(),

if request.method == 'GET':
    context = {
        # 'names': Employees.objects.all().order_by('last_name').values(),
        'special_header': "Datensätze löschen",
    }
    
# Wenn der Button ohne Auswahl gedrückt wird
elif 'id' in request.POST and request.POST['id'] == 'Mitarbeiter löschen...':
    context = {
        # 'names': Employees.objects.all().order_by('last_name').values(),
        'info': "Bitte treffen Sie zuerst eine Auswahl"
    }

else:
    id = request.POST['id']
    lastname = Employees.objects.get(id=id).last_name.upper()
    firstname = Employees.objects.get(id=id).first_name
    trash = Employees.objects.filter(id=id)
    # trash.delete()

    context = {
        # 'names': Employees.objects.all().order_by('last_name').values(),
        'success': "Datensatz für " + lastname + ", " + firstname + " wurde gelöscht"
    }

return render(request, 'delete.html', context)
```

left the outcommented parts in the code for clarification what i want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the context you pass to render is a python dictionary. No need to define it always completely; it can be filled step-by-step.
You can simply start with an empty one and add item by item wherever you want:

```
context = {}
context['key1']=xxxx
....
context['key2']=yyyy
...
...
render(request, "xyz.html", context)
```

update: add items to context always with

```
context['key_n']=xyz
```

if you use

```
context={
   'key_n': xyz
}
```

then a new context dict is created and the original context is lost.

Comment: Sounds like the perfect solution and maybe (most likely i think :-P) I'm doing something wrong, but if i define my "default context" above all if clauses in the way you describe, it gets simply ignored when rendering template....

Comment: please post your uodated code

Comment: updated my question with done code modifications

Comment: see updated answer above

Comment: yeah....that absolutely makes sense....thx, finally it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Very doable, follow these steps:

1. Move as many declarations as possible above the conditionals, and then either add to the context dictionary or re-write the values within the context dictionary through the conditionals as needed
2. Optimise the code with ternary expressions where possible

See below, which should work:

```py
def show(request):
    cur_user = request.user
    view_self_only = view_self(cur_user) and not more_rights(cur_user)
    
    if request.method == "GET":
        info = "Für sie existiert (noch) kein Datensatz in dieser Datenbank"
        if view_self_only:
            if Employees.objects.filter(employee_number=cur_user).exists():
                names = Employees.objects.filter(employee_number=cur_user)
                context = {"names": names}
            else:
                context = {"info": info}
        else:
            names = Employees.objects.all().order_by("last_name").values()
            context = {"names": names}
        return render(request, 'show.html', context)

    employee_filter = (
        Employees.objects.filter(employee_number=cur_user) 
        if view_self_only 
        else Employees.objects.all().order_by('last_name').values()
    )
    context = {'names': employee_filter}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.POST['id']
        if employee_id != 'Mitarbeiter auswählen...':
            employee = Employees.objects.filter(id=id)
            work_conditions = Employment.objects.filter(employee_id=id)
            functions = Functions.objects.filter(
                employee__functions=id).order_by('function')
            fieldsoa = FieldsOfActivity.objects.filter(
                employee__fieldsofactivity=id).order_by('field_of_activity')
            missions = Foreign_Missions.objects.filter(
                employee_id=id).order_by('-begin')
            examinations = Examinations.objects.filter(
                employee_id=id).order_by('-date')
            tot_dur_days = Foreign_Missions.objects.total_duration_days(id)
            context.update({
                'entries': employee,
                'work_conditions': work_conditions,
                'functions': functions,
                'fieldsoa': fieldsoa,
                'missions': missions,
                'examinations': examinations,
                'total_duration_days': tot_dur_days,
                'today': date.today(),
                'special_header': "Datensätze anzeigen"
            })
        else:
            context['info'] = "Bitte treffen Sie zuerst eine Auswahl"
    return render(request, 'show.html', context)
```

I've made some other slight modifications to your code to make it PEP8 compliant, but the functionality should be exactly the same now only cleaner and more DRY.

Hope this works!

Comment: Thx for your efforts, but my intention is to save codelines. so i wanted to do something like a "default content" in the beginning that applies to all following "if" clauses without having to repeat it. with your approach i can reduce a lot of text in the "context" part but alltogether itdoes not narrow the code....